# Popup Windows Possible in docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

Is it possible to have a popup window appear in response to clicking on a link or something like a link?

There is a table of possible values that I don't want to repeat in an online guide.  It would be good to put them in a popup window that would appear i response to a mouse over or a click. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://gitlab.grnet.gr/terminology/docusaurus-terminology offers a possible variation on what you're looking to do.